# Какой стек выбрать для SPA и десктопного приложения?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, oauth2, spa

Добрый день!
Подскажите какие технологии больше подходят под требования:

1. SPA.
2. Offline режим, с возможностью синхронизации в реальном времени,
   между несколькими клиентами.
3. История изменений с возможностью undo/redo.
4. Вебсокеты.
5. Десктопное приложение(возможно nw.js или electron)
6. Авторизация, права доступа.
7. Мобильное приложение(не особо важно, но хотелось бы).

Хочу найти наиболее подходящую базу данных, серверный язык и если есть то подходящий фреймворк.

Знаю js, angular, php, mysql.

Answer (score -1):

Вообще если не емкое приложение, допустим для smart-tv или аналогичного, то проще нативка(ванилла).

А так, сейчас все помешаны на ReactJS, да и с nodejs react общается на ты имея возможность единого api на back/front.

Ангуляр - ну такое, вообще его смысл теряется на фоне современных проектов.

а теперь по сборке.

1. если склоняешься к асинхронности, то node + react (back) уже по желанию (для своих апи), а так весь бэк можно и модулями node собрать и все будет работать вполне
2. C базами по сложнее. Если малые объемы данных - *sql!
3. Если много хаотичных и не структурно управляемых данных(точный контроль не имеет значения), то mongo

Ну если более серьезное приложение, то разделение вывода данных, частично с mongo, частично sql.

В общем что бы понять, что тебе нужно, нужно понимать конкретные задачи приложения, его направление и архитектуру(хотя бы его теория).

Comment: Планируется сервис для прототипирования интерфейса. Пишется он в первую очередь для обучения. 
Больше всего из поставленных целей смущает реализация offline с синхронизацией и undo/redo. Даже не представляю как такое реализовывать с mysql. 

Возможности сходи с proto.io. 

Архитектуры нету, так как не было опыта создания приложений с нуля.Чему и хочу обучиться. 

Пока выбираю подходящие инструменты..